# For large $n$, show that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{nx^{n-1}dx}{1+x^2} $ nearly equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

For large $n$, show that $$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{nx^{n-1}dx}{1+x^2} $$ nearly equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

Integrating by parts we get $$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{nx^{n-1}dx}{1+x^2}=\Bigg(\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\Bigg)^{1}_{0} - \int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{2x^{n+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$ 
The integral $$\int\limits_{0}^1 \frac{2x^{n+1}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx\leq\int\limits_{0}^1 {2x^{n+1}}dx =\frac{2}{n+2}$$
which $\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
Hence the value of the main integral is $1$. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Excellent, except for the penultimate sentence! $\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}$ evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=1$!

Comment: Oh, and it should be + not - when you integrate by parts.

Answer (score 2):

As commented:

$$\left.\left(\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\right)\right|_0^1=\frac1{1+1}-\frac0{1+0}=\frac12$$

Comment: Somehow someone/something erased the comments here. Weird. Anyone, if the commenter would like to post his comment as an answer I'll be happy to delete my answer. It's just to have one unanswered questions *less* among tens of thousands already unanswered.